# Are self-written applications welcomed here?

Tags: discussion, answers, self-promotion

How well does this community receive answers which basically suggest a program that was created by the answerer solely for the poster's requirements?

I'm toying with the idea of increasing my skill-level in a language by writing applications for people who request certain applications.

I don't mind if the community would react neutrally, I just don't want to receive downvotes if people feel I am doing something nefarious by posting my own applications.

Comment: Out of interest, on what language(s) and operating system(s) will you be focusing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I would say it is OK, as long as you clearly say that you are the author.

If the goal is really to increase your skills and thus you make the result open source, then it is actually even more acceptable than the situation described at [Acceptable to ask → build → self-answer a question for open source?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/acceptable-to-ask-%e2%86%92-build-%e2%86%92-self-answer-a-question-for-open-source) which is already considered as OK.