# Say I posted a question some time ago and ended up writing the solution myself, can I add it?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion, self-answer

Say I have asked a question on the site before, but I either received no or no satisfactory answers. Then, after too much waiting, I decide to write my own solution.

Is it okay to add that solution as answer to my own question?

Would it make a difference whether the solution I created is FLOSS ([open-source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source)) or proprietary?

Comment: This question already covers the FLOSS case: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1086/acceptable-to-ask-%e2%86%92-build-%e2%86%92-self-answer-a-question-for-open-source . So I would suggest you restrict this question to the proprietary case. Thanks :-)

Comment: Alternatively, it is also perfectly fine to close the present question if the question there is exactly what you wanted to ask :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, you are even encouraged to – see [Can I answer my own question?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) in our help system. About open-source vs. proprietary: it should of course be open-source … if the question requires that (honestly, FOSS is always a good idea). But then, as it is your own question, you are the one specifying the requirements. The answer should match those.

As you speak of your own product here, just make sure you don't forget the [obligatory full disclosure](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) that this is your own product

Comment: Oh, I am aware what entails Q&A, the question was mostly geared at the aspect of effectively plugging ones own product in such a case (FLOSS or not). Thanks, given you're a mod here, I'll take it as authoritative answer.

Comment: Just don't foget the obligatory disclosure of your authorship, which I implied (will update my answer accordingly).